# Why is the Interpreter design pattern not applicable when efficiency is a critical concern?

Tags: design-patterns, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter, state-machine

In the book Design Patterns, written by the Gang of Four, the following is stated in the 'Applicability' section of the Interpreter pattern:

> efficiency is not a critical concern. The most efficient interpreters are usually not implemented by interpreting parse trees directly but by first translating them into another form. For example, regular expressions are often transformed into state machines.

- Why is interpreting parse trees directly not efficient?
- How do state machines help in improving this efficiency?
- Are state machines more efficient then an Abstract Syntax Tree for 'interpretation' of a sentence? If so, why?

I viewed AST and state machine articles on the internet:

- https://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/samplechapter/0/3/2/1/0321112547.pdf
- https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2022/10/07/finite-state-automata/
- https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2112/2018fa/recitations/07ast/ast.pdf

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the answer to the questions stated in the problem section. The reason for that could be that I don't fully comprehend the 'Applicability' section of the Interpreter pattern. As a result not formulating the right questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most efficient interpreters are usually not implemented by interpreting parse trees directly but by first translating them into another form.

This is almost certainly true, but please note that it doesn't specify what the other form is, and nor does it imply that there is a single other form that applies to any parse tree or problem domain.

> For example, regular expressions are often transformed into state machines.

This is an example of the above. Here the problem domain is simple pattern matching where the pattern was originally specified using a regular expression. In this particular case, a state machine is generally much more efficient than trying to emulate the regular expression as an NFA (since that's what the parse tree represents), because the state machine can be followed using a single table lookup at each character position with a single auxiliary variable (representing the state). That algorithm is guaranteed linear time and constant space. Emulating the NFA, on the other hand, either requires backtracking on failure, which could lead to exponential time, or it requires maintaining a set of possible states, which means that the auxiliary storage is the size of the regular expression and the time to handle a single input character is also proportional to the size of the regular expression. (That's an approximation; each state in the NFA corresponds to a position in the regular expression, so the state count and the length of the regular expression are linearly related but not identical. But it's close enough for O-notation.)

Does that mean that state machines are always a more efficient representation than a syntax tree? Certainly not. If the problem domain were computing the value of an arithmetic expression, then state machines are complete irrelevant. But the parse tree is still not the most efficient way of evaluating the expression. Evaluating the parse tree requires a recursive traversal over the expression, for every evaluation. That means extensive use of the processor stack and lots of procedure calls, none of which is actually necessary. Converting the parse tree into a simple vector of "three-address" instructions (effectively, a virtual machine) is a very simple operation and the resulting vector of instructions can be evaluated very rapidly. (If the language being evaluated has functions, you will need a stack, but if they are just algebraic expressions with only built-in functions, then you can probably compute the needed size of an array of temporaries. You can use indices into that array as addresses in the three-address code.)

Does that mean that a virtual machine program is always a more efficient representation than a syntax tree? Again, no, although it's probably a more generally applicable technique than the state machine. (And the state machine could be considered a sort of virtual machine program, if you squint your eyes and allow a little bit of hand-waving.)

So the bottom line is that if you want efficient evaluation, you need to tailor the data structure you use to represent the semantics of an input sentence to what you know about the problem domain and the likely control flow patterns which will arise.

Comment: Hi Rici, thanks for the extensive answer. I think my vocabulary in expression interpretation was too limited. However, I managed to clarify certain concepts. I understand now what a DFA and NFA is. There differences can be expressed in time and size. However, I still don't fully understand everything. Why is interpretation of an abstract syntax tree less efficient then interpretation of a FSA? Why can abstract syntax trees be seen as a NFA? Why would we use an AST as an intermediate 'form' and translate that into a FSA? Why not directly translate it into a FSA?

Comment: @NiekBeijloos: Are you specifically interested in parsing and interpreting regular expressions? Or is your question more generally about ASTs?

Comment: More general about ASTs and FSAs with focus on interpretation efficiency.

Comment: @niek I don't believe DFAs have any role in the general case and the quote from the Gang of 4 is certainly not implying that they do.

Comment: The sentence you quoted starts with the words "**For example, regular expressions**, meaning "As an example, in the case where the language being parsed is a description of regular expressions, ...". You can match a regular expression against an input by interpreting the syntax tree for the regular expression, but that will result in an inefficient solution if you are going to use the same regular expression several times. For those applications, it is common to compile the regular expression into a FSA. But that is specific to the problem domain of parsing **regular expressions**.

Comment: @Niek, I just dug out my old copy of the book to verify that I'm correctly interpreting the quote in context, and I noticed that there is example code for the use of the Interpreter pattern with regular expressions. But I don't think that's relevant unless you are actually interested in that particular application.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, appreciated. I think we are close in resolving my confusion. I quote you: 'You can match a regular expression against an input by interpreting the syntax tree for the regular expression, but that will result in an inefficient solution if you are going to use the same regular expression several times. For those applications, it is common to compile the regular expression into a FSA.' **Why/how will the syntax tree result in an inefficient solution in case we use the same regular expression several times?**  **And how does a FSA overcome that inefficiency?**

Comment: @Niek: I already answered that in the answer above: the FSA is deterministic; it can be traversed with one simple table lookup at each character position. If you interpret the AST, you frequently find yourself with two options at an AST node. If the node is alternation (`|`), you have to explore one possible branch, then return to the current input position to explore the other branch. If the node is repetition, you try repeating once more; if that fails, again you have to fall back. All that try-and-fallback is not only time consuming, it can lead to exponential blowup.

Comment: I also asked you if you were interested in parsing and interpreting regular expressions, and you replied that it wasn't your focus. But if you actually are curious about that problem domain, I suggest you start by reviewing a standard textbook such as the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), which devotes a whole chapter to explaining the various algorithms used to produce efficient regular expression matchers. Reproducing that chapter as a SO comment is neither practical nor useful.

Comment: Both DFA and AST are O(n) time complexity in interpretation. You state: 'If the node is repetition, you try repeating once more; if that fails, again you have to fall back. All that try-and-fallback is not only time consuming, it can lead to exponential blowup.' I can derive from this that ASTs don't fully adhere to O(n) time complexity, but O(cn)! How is this try-and-fallback mechanism implemented in case of a DFA? Does this not result in the same time complexity? Do you have examples where I could see the difference between DFA and AST in terms of time complexity?

Comment: @niek: an example of a regular expression which takes exponential time to match using direct interpretation (i.e. with the AST) is `(0*1|.)*` matching a string consisting only of `0`s. That particular regex can be simplified to `.*`; compiling to a DFA produces a DFA equivalent to the simplified version. No matter how complex the regex is, compiling to a DFA produces the simplest equivalent, which can always be matched without backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

[image: LinearLisp vs Python vs MS JScript]

AST-walking interpreters do not have to be slow.

In fact, you can implement one for .NET 6 with run time performance **in the same ballpark as Python 3.10**, and in just a few hundreds of lines of C# and easily extensible.

I've done it:

https://github.com/ysharplanguage/LinearLisp

I've dubbed the technique as "full linearization" (of said AST).

Getting rid as much as possible of references to instances of reference types is key to letting automatic memory management, likewise, go on vacation for as many CPU cycles as possible (hence, avoid paying for its overhead during the evaluation of terms in expressions, of expressions in special forms or other syntactic sugar constructs, etc).

It isn't too hard to see why full linearization certainly counts among the best friends of cache locality, also.

(Contrariwise, frantically walking naively implemented ASTs full of references all over the place on the heap - as it has been traditionally done for long for such interpreters - is a sure way of throwing cache locality out of the window.)

So, don't take my word for it, and feel free to just check out the upper bounds used in the various micro benchmarks for the experiment linked above, and see for yourself that most of these run in under a second or two on modern machines.

Not hours, not minutes. Just within seconds.